# Java Selenium FirefoxDriver ignores Proxy settings

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

My following Java Code should open a Firefox Window and navigate to 
`http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup` so I can see if my proxy settings worked.

```
    final String proxy = "86.100.118.44:80";

    Proxy p = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
    p.setHttpProxy(proxy)
         .setFtpProxy(proxy)
         .setSslProxy(proxy);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, p);

    WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
    browser.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup");
```

but the Website shows my original IP address, not the proxys one. I already tried different Proxies from different sources and also different IP-lookup-sites.

Here is what the console shows:

```
Okt 02, 2016 10:37:57 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMATION: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1475440677875   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 59000
1475440678867   Marionette  INFO    startBrowser     11b45228-3a63-4639-9ba3-777c16a0cab8
Okt 02, 2016 10:37:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMATION: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Here is the official Documentation: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Proxy support is simply not implemented in the current version of geckoDriver yet.

People claim workarounds exist.

Source:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/97